# C++ protobuf SerializedData

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I need to get `serializedData` (like in C#) in C++ for `google::protobuf::FileDescriptor` object.

In C++ code I have `google::protobuf::FileDescriptor` object. And I need to get something like `ByteString SerializedData` in C# (The original serialized binary form of this descriptor.)

Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FileDescriptor::CopyTo(FileDescriptorProto * proto)`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#FileDescriptor.CopyTo.details) to copy the contents to a [`FileDescriptorProto`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor.pb#FileDescriptorProto), which is a regular `Message` that you can serialize using any of the [`SerializeTo...`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite) functions.

Comment: By the way. Maybe you know why I have difference between C# and C++ array data? I use: google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto proto; ... proto.SerializeToArray(arr, size); arr differs from c# array.

Comment: Actually diff is small. C++ data size is 110, C# data size is 107. Most symbols are equals. In the middle of sequence I have difference.

Comment: Try deserializing the proto, then serializing it to text format ([`TextFormat::PrintToString`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format#TextFormat.PrintToString.details)), so you can see what the actual difference is. `protoc` can also do this conversion for you, when passed the path to the original `.proto` files that describe the message (`FileDescriptorProto` etc.).